# finding nearby iphone device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

is it possible to find nearby iphone through iphone sdk? how can i identify it?i want to
store that device (may be ID), and find out when the device comes near my device when i open my app? any idea please?is possible to do in iphone 4.1?

Answer (score 1):

There is a "bump" API available that you might be able to use to get information from another phone.

http://bu.mp/apitutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

See GameKit. You can only identify other devices running your app though.

The alternative way is to send your device ID and location to a server; there are obvious privacy implications (and I suspect the SDK agreement says you have to obtain consent before invading their privacy like this). "Bump" does exactly this but requires that both sides already know that they're near each other.

Comment: hi, both end must open the application to find the device? there is no way to find from one end?